# Property 'database' does not exist on type 'AngularFireAuth'

Tags: angular, firebase

```
getUsers() {
  return this.af.database.list('users');
}

getUser(userId: string): Observable<User> {
  return this.af.database.object('users/' + userId);
}

this.af.database
   .object('')
   .update(updatedUserData)
   .then(() => {
     resultSubject.next(user);
   })
```

My database word is giving an error and even though I read the document, I don't understand what to do.

Comment: Can you describe more your problem which line you get error and do you call this line `this.af.database
      .object('')
      .update(updatedUserData)
      .then(() => {
        resultSubject.next(user);
      })`. Also, I find this example in angular fire repository. you should inject AngularFireDatase in constructor. [Source](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/sample/src/app/database/database.component.ts)

Comment: 'Property 'database' does not exist on type 'AngularFireAuth'.ts 'when i write this code -- return this.af.database.list('users'); -- i get this error

Comment: Can you show how you declare `this.af` in your constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firebase has been updated and the document has changed, the solution is;
"this.afFireStore.collection"afFireStore libery = AngularFirestore